# How to create crystal report for an invoice which has many items

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, report

I want to make `crystal report` for invoice which have many items as shown below:

[image]

But, the problem is if invoice have many items, invoice number is repeating with the item.
when I create report in access with same database report show like the image above. 
Please help me with this.

I am working on `VisualStudio C#`

Comment: Please add an image directly.  Any links files can disappear and your question becomes very confusing.

Comment: it depends on in which section are you placing the invoice number and in which section you are placing the items?

Comment: what is your source? stored procedure from mssql? @arippe

Comment: i used access database